# Peewee: Get unique constraint violating field in IntegrityError

Tags: python, peewee

I have a model with two fields

```
class User(Model):

    email = CharField(unique = True)
    username = CharField(unique = True)
    password_hash = CharField()
```

When i save this model and  either the email or username aldready exists in the database, how would i get which field is violating the unique constraint when creating a new record.

I tried nothing, i couldnt find anything online.

Comment: 1. You should not handle integrity errors inside code, you need to avoid them by checking conditions before. Integrity error means that your request failed and changes done within it should be rolled back. 2. Your question depends on database backend you are using, e.g. postgresql has `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`, MySQL has `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and so on

Comment: Could you please tell me how I could do that?

Sorry am newbie

Comment: What kind of documentation do you need? Peewee has [OnConflict](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#OnConflict), but it's only supports postgres and sqlite AFAIK

Comment: Garbage comments, sudden_appearance -- you can handle them in code just fine and this is a normal operation for databases that don't support ON CONFLICT (older sqlites) or if you want to take some additional/special actions. wwfbb - you can try to read the column name / info out of the exception message.

Comment: Also sudden_appearance, Peewee's `on_conflict()` supports sqlite, mysql and postgres, although there differences in what types of operations are supported by the db itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of catching a Sqlite unique constraint violation:

```
User.create(username='u1')
try:
    User.create(username='u1')
except peewee.IntegrityError as exc:
    print(exc.args)
    col = exc.args[0].split(': ')[-1]
    print(col)
```

Prints:

```
('UNIQUE constraint failed: user.username',)
user.username
```